# Is there a way to svn co a local copy to a remote directory?

Tags: svn, ssh

Is there a way to svn check out a local working copy to a remote directory?

Running the import command works:

> svn import -m "Testing import" my-working-copy.dev svn+ssh://root@somedomain.com/root/my-working-copy

However, svn co doesnt:

> svn co file://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/my-working-repo/trunk svn+ssh://root@somedomain.com/root/my-working-copy

And the error it outputs:

> stdin: is not a tty
>
> svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://root@somedomain.com/root/my-working-copy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're not simply looking for [`svn commit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re06.html):

No, there is no way to do this just by using Subversion.

Workarounds:

- Since you already have ssh access to the remote machine, you can mount the remote repository locally using [`sshfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) and check out like you would to local filesystem.
- You can also check out locally then [`scp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) to remote machine.
- You can connect to remote machine over ssh, and run a checkout against the repository on your local machine through svn+ssh.

All of this can be scripted of course.

Comment: I second the first suggestion: `sshfs`. If for some reason `sshfs` was not an option, I would consider `rsync` as an alternative to `scp`. @vls: about the third option, do I need an ssh server running on my machine? if not, could you detail or give an example? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `svn` working copy is not a repository.  You can do a *checkout* only from the repository and not from the working copy.